# New (not that much) to Linux/Ubuntu. Thinking of replacing Windows and also help regarding AMD Radeon graphics card

Tags: drivers, windows, graphics, radeon

I recently bought a new Lenovo Y40-80 laptop and it comes with an AMD Radeon R9 M275 graphics card. I know this is not a high-end graphics card. I am not a hardcore gamer, and play only a few games like TF2 and DOTA2.

Now the query: In Windows, I can easily enable it for a game (DOTA2, etc.) through AMD Catalyst Control Center. What I wanted to know was how can I use my graphics card for an installed game while on Ubuntu? Or is it not possible at all? Because if I decide to go ahead with the scenario that I completely remove Windows, it would be a waste as I won't be able to use the graphics card.

Looking forward to hearing from the community. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Your question is too broad for this format. This is not a discussion forum but a Q&A site.

Comment: Deleted the discussion paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu should work OK with this laptop. You can test it first by booting from LiveCD.

You can install  Catalyst Control Center and switch adapters in Ubuntu.

It is done by running in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
```

Or it can be done in GUI

System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers

**But you will have to switch adapters manually.**

Windows games will not run well on Ubuntu. Some of them will run using wine. But do not expect good performance.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So, when I install the Catalyst Control Center for Ubuntu, how do I set the Game to "High Performance" just like one does in Windows?

Comment: Game.exe is a Windows program, it will not run on Ubuntu. Dota2 can be installed using Steam.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Please check the edited response.

Comment: @user244405 Updated the answer.

Comment: I think I was not clear. I know that DOTA2 runs on Linux/Ubuntu. My particular question in this regard would be, how do I set DOTA2 to be running in "High-Performance" in AMD Radeon? In Windows, one can select "SampleGame.exe" in the Catalyst Center and just select "High-Performance" there. Hope you understand my point.  :)

Comment: You can't set applications to be run with a specific adapter. You will have to switch to high performance all system then log off and log on.

Comment: Oh, OK. So you mean to say that for Ubuntu/Linux, for the AMD graphics card, it's either all applications high-performance, or all low-performance, unlike Windows, where we can specify this for individual application?

Comment: This is correct

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install AMD Catalyst Control Centre on Ubuntu as well.

If you need to download it and update it manually you can use the `sudo dpkg --install package_file` command in the terminal. "package_file" here being the name of the file you are trying to install.